# What is the difference between Version and 'Runtime Version' in .Net?

Tags: .net, runtime, version, rhino-mocks, .net-assembly

When I open the properties window of one of the referenced dlls in my project in Visual Studio I see a Version and also a runtime version .

Actually it is Rhino.Mocks library I am checking. And I see

- Runtime Version : v2.0.50727
- Version : 3.6.0.0

What is the difference? (Does it mean I am not able to use 3.6.0.0 of the Rhino Mocks?)

Comment: please read the description for tags you use. [assembly] is about assembly language progamming. use [.net-assembly] instead.

Comment: Thanks for the advice; I have not noticed that tag's existence before.

Comment: on the other hand.. I get 2 reputation for retagging :D

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Runtime is the version of the CLR (or .NET framework) the DLL needs (usually as a minimum), version is the DLL's version.

So long as you have the minimum runtime installed, it should be usable. However as a general rule it is usually best to select the latest version of the library for the latest runtime support etc.

Comment: To add to it, Runtime Version, Version or any other property can be clicked upon to see its description at the bottom of the property window.

Comment: So for most practical purposes, we would refer to "Version" as the version, and not the "Runtime Version"; this is somewhat confusing... wish they would call the "Runtime Version"  a new name such as "CLR needed" or something such as that ! ...