# What is the difference between "Runtime Version" and "Version"?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

In Visual Studio (2012 in my case) when you click on a dll in References, the properties come up.  In this properties windows, "Version" and "Runtime Version" are both listed.

What is the difference between these two?  I need to download an old version of a dll so that it will work with this solution, but do not know which version is the dll version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Runtime version is the .Net framework version that the library was built against. Version is the version of the DLL itself.

Answer (score 1):

Runtime version refers to the version of the .NET CLR and version refers to the DLL version.

Answer (score 1):

Runtime is the version of the CLR (or .NET framework?) the DLL needs (usually as a minimum), version is the DLL's version.

So long as you have the minimum runtime installed, it should be usable. However as a general rule it is usually best to select the latest version of the library for the latest runtime support etc

[Source Dublicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573942/what-is-the-difference-between-version-and-runtime-version-in-net)