# Why does Nuget show EF V6 and References shows V4?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, entity-framework, version

I am getting this error:

`Assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework' with identity 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' uses 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'EntityFramework' with identity 'EntityFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'`

Which I am interpreting as:

`"You've got V4. We need V6."`

Now, when I check the version in Nuget Package Manager it says I have V6.1.3 installed.

But looking at the references section in the Solution Explorer shows V4.

*Why is the references showing V4 when V6.1.3 is installed?*

[image]

---

**Update**

I uninstalled everything that depended on EF and finally EF itself.

After reinstalling them all, the References section now shows V6  (though runtime version is still set to 4).

I would still like to understand why there might be differences between the two.

Comment: That is correct. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573942/what-is-the-difference-between-version-and-runtime-version-in-net

Comment: Ta, that's helpful to know